# AWS Sagemaker Labeling - Access Granted but Not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

AWS newbie. I am following the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-getting-started.html) in the video and the steps but I am unable to create labels[enter link description here](https://console.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/groundtruth).

I've granted the users and roles access to the s3 bucket, and yet..

```
MultipleValidationErrors: There were 2 validation errors: * MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Bucket' in params * MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'Key' in params - The S3 bucket 'null' you entered in Input dataset location cannot be reached. Either the bucket does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it. If the bucket does not exist, update Input dataset location with a new S3 URI. If the bucket exists, give the IAM entity you are using to create this labeling job permission to read and write to this S3 bucket, and try your request again.
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot access the link to your labeling job. Can you paste more details like the steps you are performing to create the labeling job? Also does the issue comes while submitting the job or while labeling the data as a worker?

It looks your SageMaker Execution role does not have permissions to access the S3 bucket where the training data is hosted. There are two different roles here.

1. Your logged in AWS user role which allows you to access SageMaker GroundTruth.
2. The `SageMaker Execution Role` which is used by SageMaker GroundTruth service to access the S3 bucket where the training data is sitting.

From the error log you shared, it looks the `SageMaker Execution Role` does have the right access to the S3 bucket.